# Jquery Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have been looking at a few post on Stack trying to get a simple form validation working but all it does is disabled my submit button. Its meant to remove the disable once they've entered text inside the input field.

So Far

**Jquery**

```
$('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);

$('input').change(function(){
    if($('input').val() != ''){ 
        $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
    } else {
        $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required placeholder="Name"/>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address"/>
    <input name="submit" id="subscribe" type="submit" value="Subscribe for free"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you disabling the submit button when there is some text inside the input field ? like here , `if($('input').val() != ''){ 
                 $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true); }`

Comment: As dreamweiver pointed, you should just maybe set disable to "false" instead of "true" ?

Comment: Ops had it the wrong way round haha thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for every input by using classes that are added to all fields that are requiered. If the user changes one of them and there is still no input, then the button while stay disabled:

jQuery:

```
   $('input.required').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != ''){ 
             $(this).removeClass('required',true);
        }else{
             $(this).addClass('required',true);
        }

        //check the length to enable or disable submit
        if($(".required").length == 0){ 
             $('#subscribe').attr('disabled',false);
        }else{
             $('#subscribe').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
```

html:

```
 <form action="send.php" method="post">
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="required" placeholder="Name" />
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" />
            <input name="submit" id="subscribe" type="submit" value="Subscribe for free" />
</form>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VGfBg/3/).

However keep in mind that this solution only works with javascript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your statements in `if-else`, let me know if you are trying something different apart from this--

```
$('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);

        $('input').change(function(){
            if($('input').val() != ''){ 
                  $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            }else{
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
            }
        });
```

Fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/UcQhw/

Answer (score 1):

You got to swap statements in if-else block. Also use $(this) to get the source of event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/seGH8/)**

```
  $('input:submit').attr('disabled', true);
   $('input').change(function () {
       if ($(this).val() !== '') {
           $('input:submit').attr('disabled', false);
       } else {
           $('input:submit').prop('disabled', true);
       }
   });
```

if you want to check that all text field must not be empty then you have to iterate through all inputs. You should assign `class` to get sepecific textboxes instead of getting all on page. You can use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to get elements by class.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/seGH8/1/)**

```
$('input:submit').attr('disabled', true);
$('.cls').change(function () {
   blankFields = $('.cls').filter(function () {
       return this.value == '';
   });
   if (blankFields.length === 0) $('input:submit').attr('disabled', false);
   else $('input:submit').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: But this will only check the input that has just been changed, ignoring the other(s).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have refined your code a bit, and its working as you intended

**JS CODE:**

```
 $('#subscribe').attr('disabled',true);

    $('input').change(function(){
        if($('input').val() != ''){ 

             $('#subscribe').attr('disabled',false);
        }else{
             //$('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled');
         $('#subscribe').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/VGfBg/1/) on JS Fiddle

happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code:

```
 //$('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);

    $('input').change(function(){
        if($('input').val() != ''){ alert(1);
             $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
        }else{alert(2);
             $('input:submit').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/WchJ9/